# create php variable from string

Tags: php

Hello i have a script that extract company names from a string. I want that the extracted names to be converted to php variable. So for example first result Real Coffee Sweeden must be converted to `$RealCoffeeSweeden = 0` so i can assign a value to it

```
 $test='/showname/0406741848                              : Real Coffee Sweeden
/showname/0406741849                              : Healthzone SE
/showname/16133663413                             : FREE
/showname/16133663414                             : RadioPlantes Canada
/showname/16133663417                             : Dealsoftoday.Eu Canada
/showname/16136995593                             : FREE
/showname/16136995594                             : Club White Smile Canada
/showname/16138007442                             : FREE
/showname/16138007547                             : Mybitwave.com Canada
/showname/16465596150                             : BABY
/showname/16465696956                             : FREE
/showname/16465696957                             : FREE
/showname/16467419944                             : Mybitwave.com UK
/showname/16469181975                             : FREE
/showname/21501350                                : SecureSurf.EU NO
/showname/21501351                                : FileCloud365 Norwegian
/showname/21501352                                : FREE
/showname/21501353                                : RadioPlantes Norwegian
';


$myRows= explode("\n", $test);

foreach( $myRows as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $value);

    $result[] =  $pieces[1];
}

foreach ($result as $res){
    $res // covert to php variable
    //example: $RealCoffeeSweeden = 0;
}
```

Comment: not able to test, but you want variable variables, eg after foreach 
. `$$res = $res; '  // creates variable named $res

Comment: Variable variables, demo: https://eval.in/653810. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Did you notice, you have more than one name `FREE` for example, what are you going to do with those names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array for that. But if you want to do it the way you write, you can simply do something like that:

```
foreach( $myRows as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $value);

    $res = str_replace(' ', '', $pieces[1]); // replace whitespaces for valid names
    $$res = 0; // note the double dollar signs
}
```

If you want to use an array tho, do something like this:

```
$result = [];
foreach( $myRows as $key => $value) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $value);

    $key = str_replace(' ', '', $pieces[1]);
    $result[$key] = 0;
}
```

According to your comment, change second last line in the foreach loop with following:

```
$res = str_replace(' ', '', $res) . '_f';
```

Comment: ok this is working, and if i want to add _f  `$RealCoffeeSweeden_f` to the `$RealCoffeeSweeden` how shold i make it?:)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try it this way

```
  $my_array = explode("\n", $test);
  foreach($my_array as $key => $value {
     $my_string = explode(':', $value)
      ${str_replace(' ','', $my_string[1])} = $my_string;
      echo $$my_string; 
  }
```

Comment: that's pretty neat. This could go right into the first foreach, the 2nd foreach wouldn't be needed

Comment: @Duane  the code is for build dinamilcally the var  .. for obtain the string the OP should use explode  .. in a proper nested foreach ..

Comment: Oh there is another typo I didnt recognize (missing ' before Real..Sweeden). The second loop is not needed in any solution.